# ASP.NET MVC - submit not working with validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have an ajax form, with some validation rules using jquery but for some reason submit button is not working.

```
<div class="modal-body">
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveNotices", "Lookup", null, new { @id = "noticeForm"}))
            {
                {
                    // Html.EnableClientValidation(true);
                    // Html.ValidationSummary(true);
                }

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.Consumer.FirstName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Consumer.FirstName, new { @id = "firstN", @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.Consumer.FirstName)
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.Consumer.LastName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Consumer.LastName, new { @id = "lastN", @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.Consumer.LastName)
                </div>

                ... more code here ... (this does not influence btw)

                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" id="ntSubmit" onclick="checkValid()"/>
            }
        </div>
```

And here is my model

```
public class Consumer
{
    // [Required, MaxLength(25)]

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class PlateViewModel
{
    public List<Notice> Notices { get; set; }
    public Consumer Consumer { get; set; }
}
```

Main form is inside a bootstrap-modal.
Scripts are included (@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval"))
I have also tried to see if somehow ajax finished and call a method based on OnSuccess, OnComplete or OnFailure but it never goes there. The controller is not hit neither

Inside web.config

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

What have I done wrong?

Ajax options: 
`var ajaxOpt = new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "redValid", OnComplete = "redValid", OnFailure = "fail" };`

Ajax form is called with these options (not null as I showed in first code)

CheckValid:

```
var checkValid = function () {
    if ($("#firstN").valid() && $("#lastN").valid()) {
        console.log("Inside validation");
        // $("#myModal").modal('hide');
    };
};
```

Comment: What is `checkValid()`?

Comment: I have added now code for checkValid()

Comment: What is the purpose of `checkValid()` - if you have client side validation enabled it not required - the form will not submit is you have validation errors. I suspect you are dynamically loading form (i.e it does not exist in the page when you first render the page), in which case you need to re-parse the validator (and why an earth do you change the default `id` attributes (the html helper renders `id="FirstName"` but you change it to `id="firstN"`?)

Comment: It is used only to hide bootstrap modal.